Input tensor shape mismatch when converting deep learning esrgan model
I am trying to convert the uncompressed super resolution deep learning architecture ESRGAN, from this source.
Specifically, I am trying my hands on full integer quantization. Here is the code:
main.py
import quant_test as qt


def main():
    qt.calibrate_model()
    # qt.evaluate_model()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


quant_test.py
import os
import paths
import logging
import validate
import calibrate

# Download latest version
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def calibrate_model():
    calibrate.quantize_and_test_model()


def evaluate_model():
    validation_images = [
        os.path.join(paths.low_res_images_save_path, img)
        for img in os.listdir(paths.low_res_images_save_path)
    ]

    psnr_results, ssim_results = validate.compute_metrics(validation_images)
    return psnr_results, ssim_results

calibrate.py
import tensorflow as tf
import paths
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image


def representative_data_gen():
    print("Generator started")
    for image_file in os.listdir(paths.calibration_images):
        image_path = os.path.join(paths.calibration_images, image_file)
        img = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
        # Ensure the input image is at least 64x64 and is downsampled using bicubic interpolation
        # Resize factor of 4 for demonstration (considering the model produces x4 super resolution)
        img = img.resize((img.width // 4, img.height // 4), Image.BICUBIC)  # Downsample
        img = img.resize((img.width * 4, img.height * 4), Image.BICUBIC)  # Upsample to original size

        # Convert image to numpy array and cast to float32
        img_array = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)

        # Normalize the image data to 0-1
        img_array /= 255.0

        # Add batch dimension (model expects a batch dimension)
        img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

        print(f"Yielding image of shape {img_array.shape}")
        # Yield the image (the function expects a list of inputs for the model)
        yield [img_array]


def load_model(model_path):
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
    input_shape = model.signatures['serving_default'].inputs[0].shape.as_list()
    print("Original model input shape:", input_shape)
    return model


def convert_to_tflite(model_path):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model_path)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    return tflite_model


def save_tflite_model(tflite_model, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)


def setup_and_test_tflite_model(tflite_model, input_shape):
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    scale, zero_point = input_details[0]['quantization']
    interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], input_shape)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    input_data = np.random.rand(*input_shape).astype(np.float32)
    input_data = (input_data / scale + zero_point).astype(np.int8)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()

    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    print("Output data shape:", output_data.shape)
    print("Expected input shape:", input_details[0]['shape'])
    print("Expected input type:", input_details[0]['dtype'])


def quantize_and_test_model():
    model_path = paths.og_model_path
    model = load_model(model_path)
    tflite_model = convert_to_tflite(model_path)
    save_tflite_model(tflite_model, paths.tflite_model_path)

    # Example size to test dynamic input capability
    new_input_shape = [1, 300, 300, 3]
    setup_and_test_tflite_model(tflite_model, new_input_shape)

paths.py:
import kagglehub
import tensorflow as tf

path = kagglehub.model_download("kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2/esrgan-tf2")
print("Path to model files:", path)

calibration_images = "C:/a_Skola/ImageSuperResolution/python/datasets/calibration_test"
og_model_path = "C:/Users/darks/.cache/kagglehub/models/kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2/esrgan-tf2/1"

# Load your pre-trained ESRGAN model
uncompressed_model = tf.saved_model.load(og_model_path)

ground_truth_images_path = "C:/a_Skola/ImageSuperResolution/python/datasets/Validation_Dataset/ground_truth"
low_res_images_save_path = "C:/a_Skola/ImageSuperResolution/python/datasets/Validation_Dataset/low_res"

tflite_model_path = "C:/a_Skola/ImageSuperResolution/python/models/esrgan_fiq.tflite"

validate.py
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio as compare_psnr
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as compare_ssim
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import paths

# Load the original and quantized models
original_model = tf.saved_model.load(paths.og_model_path)
quantized_model = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=paths.tflite_model_path)

# Prepare the quantized model for inference
quantized_model.allocate_tensors()
input_details = quantized_model.get_input_details()
output_details = quantized_model.get_output_details()


def evaluate_model(image_path, model, quantized=False):
    img = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
    factor = 4
    new_width = (img.width // factor) * factor
    new_height = (img.height // factor) * factor
    img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.BICUBIC)
    img_array = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32) / 255.0
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

    if quantized:
        img_array = (img_array - 0.5) * 255  # Assuming quantization to [-128, 127]
        img_array = np.asarray(img_array, dtype=np.int8)

        quantized_model.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img_array)
        quantized_model.invoke()
        # here the up-scaling (inference) is performed
        output_data = quantized_model.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
        output_data = output_data.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    else:
        # Inference for original model
        output_data = model(img_array, training=False)

    output_image = tf.cast(tf.clip_by_value(output_data[0], 0, 255), tf.uint8).numpy()
    return img_array[0], output_data


def compute_metrics(validation_dataset):
    psnr_scores, ssim_scores = [], []
    for image_file in validation_dataset:
        """Tuple unpacking"""
        original_image, super_res_image = evaluate_model(image_file, original_model)
        _, quantized_super_res_image = evaluate_model(image_file, quantized_model, quantized=True)

        psnr_original = compare_psnr(original_image, super_res_image)
        psnr_quantized = compare_psnr(original_image, quantized_super_res_image)
        ssim_original = compare_ssim(original_image, super_res_image, multichannel=True)
        ssim_quantized = compare_ssim(original_image, quantized_super_res_image, multichannel=True)

        psnr_scores.append((psnr_original, psnr_quantized))
        ssim_scores.append((ssim_original, ssim_quantized))

    return psnr_scores, ssim_scores

According to the information regarding the ESRGAN model from the first source, we know that

it works best on bicubically downsampled images (the dataset I used is bicubically downsampled)
the input resolution of images needs to be at least 64x64 (I adhere to this rule)
The upscaling factor is x4
The input image must be of float 32, converted using tf.cast(image, tf.float32) (I have a similar conversion)
The image must be of 4 dimensions, [batch_size, height, width, 3]. To perform super resolution on a single image, use tf.expand_dims(image, 0) to add the batch dimension (This has also been taken into account)

For the calibration dataset, I made things as simple as possible and only used 5 images. I tried with a DIV2K dataset with many images of high resolution but considering that it took 7+ hours without completing I decided I didn't want to try that again.
The problem I have is when I try to convert the uncompressed model using my representative dataset, there seems to be a strange input tensor shape mismatch. From my code I have deduced that the original model has an input shape of [None, None, None, 3], but for whatever reason, the TensorFlow Lite version expects an input shape of [1, 1, 1, 3], and I have no idea why.
Here are the complete logs of the warning and error messages (where the calibration set only had 1 image to save time):
C:\a_Skola\ImageSuperResolution\python\ESRGAN\venv\Scripts\python.exe -X pycache_prefix=C:\Users\darks\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2024.1\cpython-cache "C:/pycharm_prof/PyCharm 2024.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 16127 --file C:\a_Skola\ImageSuperResolution\python\models\main.py 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 241.14494.241)
2024-04-30 11:36:51.314483: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-04-30 11:36:52.639290: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Warning: Looks like you're using an outdated `kagglehub` version, please consider updating (latest version: 0.2.4)
Path to model files: C:\Users\darks\.cache\kagglehub\models\kaggle\esrgan-tf2\tensorFlow2\esrgan-tf2\1
2024-04-30 11:36:55.624905: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
WARNING: Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#1081 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
Original model input shape: [None, None, None, 3]
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
W0000 00:00:1714469972.124224   31916 tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:390] Ignored output_format.
W0000 00:00:1714469972.126253   31916 tf_tfl_flatbuffer_helpers.cc:393] Ignored drop_control_dependency.
2024-04-30 11:39:32.131686: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:83] Reading SavedModel from: C:/Users/darks/.cache/kagglehub/models/kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2/esrgan-tf2/1
2024-04-30 11:39:32.153435: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:51] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2024-04-30 11:39:32.154235: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:146] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: C:/Users/darks/.cache/kagglehub/models/kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2/esrgan-tf2/1
2024-04-30 11:39:32.289252: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:388] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
2024-04-30 11:39:32.300202: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:234] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2024-04-30 11:39:32.758497: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:218] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: C:/Users/darks/.cache/kagglehub/models/kaggle/esrgan-tf2/tensorFlow2/esrgan-tf2/1
2024-04-30 11:39:32.872781: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:317] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 741341 microseconds.
2024-04-30 11:39:33.008342: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:268] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
Generator started
Yielding image of shape (1, 288, 288, 3)
fully_quantize: 0, inference_type: 6, input_inference_type: INT8, output_inference_type: INT8
Output data shape: (1, 1200, 1200, 3)
Expected input shape: [1 1 1 3]
Expected input type: <class 'numpy.int8'>

Process finished with exit code 0

I have to convert this model so that I can benchmark its performance, including PSNR, SSIM, Inference time, etc.
What might be the problem?
